# Ideas on how to display/present HTML tags on a webpage

Tags: html, css, tags

Is there a way to write HTML onto a webpage, but have it rendered as text?

Let me explain: I want to build a webpage with a discussion on HTML. Therefore there will be sections like

```
<div>
    <p>
        <span>Hello world</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

I would like that to formatted properly with indentation, and perhaps even have the tags in a different colour scheme.

I'm fully aware that I could write the styling for this myself, but surely someone has already written and made available a stylesheet, a LESS mixin, or perhaps a jQuery plugin which recognises and formats for me?

UPDATE: Just to make people aware, I realise that I have to HTML-encode the tags (&lt; and &gt;). But that doesn't help with the formatting/presentation, and it's the formatting/presentation that I'm looking for help with.

Comment: > = &gt;    < = &lt;  or php: `echo htmlspecialchars('your html here');`

Comment: and use <pre> </pre> for indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for SyntaxHighlighter. See [demo page here](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/demo/)

Answer (score 26):

Use the `<xmp>` tag instead of `<pre>`.

E.g.

```
<xmp>

<html>
<body>This is my html inside html.</body>
</html>

</xmp>
```

Comment: as you see tags are in red color and text in black how to do that..?

Comment: Note that `xmp` is obsolete and has been removed from HTML5: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp

Comment: While obsolete in the sense that its use is discouraged, none of pre, code, or other similar tags achieve the same affect, and as of this writing xmp still works in Firefox and Chrome, at least.  If you want to have a file you can look at yourself (i.e. unescaped < and > tags) rendered as html on the page, xmp does this and none of the other suggested alternatives do.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert < and > to [HTML entities](http://centricle.com/tools/html-entities/).

```
&lt;div&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;
        &lt;span&gt;Hello world&lt;/span&gt;
    &lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
```

As for color coding, look into [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/). Here are some [examples](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styles/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

As regards to escaping characters, what you need to escape are “<” (as `&lt;`) and “&” (as `&amp;`). If you use automated tools, make sure they handle these characters.

To preserve the formatting (line breaks and spacing), you can use `<pre>` markup. It is best used so that the first line starts immediately (on the same line) after the `<pre>` tag and the last line is immediately (without linebreak) followed by the end tag `</pre>`. Otherwise some browsers may display extra empty lines.

The `<pre>` markup implies a system-dependent monospace font by default. This can of course be changed in CSS. The markup also implies font size reduction on most browsers, presumably to cope with the properties of monospace fonts; you may therefore wish to set font-size to a value (maybe 100%) to match your design.

Alternatively, you can wrap the code inside any block element (like `<div>`) and set white-space: pre for it in CSS. This means that the formatting is preserved but the font face and size are the same as for surrounding text (unless you explicitly set it).

You may additionally use `<code>` markup to indicate the content as computer code. It, too, sets the font to monospace and reduced-size but is otherwise purely logical. If you wish to indicate the language used, then class=language-html would be the way suggested in HTML5 drafts. This has no direct impact as such; it just makes it easier to style your HTML code samples consistently and to recognize them in JavaScript processing if needed.

Example:

```
<pre><code class=language-html>&lt;div>
    &lt;p>
        &lt;span>Hello world&lt;/span>
    &lt;/p>
    &lt;/div></code></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

As above I it is always a good idea to use the HTML characters to display the demonstration of HTML so always use `**&lt;**` for **<** and `**&gt;**` for **<** or if you want to be a bit more helpful to your target user then you could use a code highlighter such as [Code Highlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/)

Hope this helps!