# display html code in html page

Tags: php, html

Am using this following method to display `html` code in html page

```
 <?php $userSuppliedHTML = "<div>snaoj</div>"; ?>
 <code><?php echo htmlentities($userSuppliedHTML, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></code>
```

Since my page are `html` so i can't run above method because its `php`

so i decide to use this following method based on only `html`

```
        <blockquote>
            <pre>
             <code>
               <div>snaoj</div>
                My pre-formatted "quoted" code here.
              </code>
            </pre>
        </blockquote>

pre{
                font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace, serif;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                overflow: auto;
                width: auto;
                padding: 5px;
                background-color: #eee;
                width: 650px;
                padding-bottom: 20px;
                max-height: 600px;
            }
```

Problem is this method doesn't

can some one help me how do i display codes on web pages

Comment: If you convert it in .php. what's the problem?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh but how can i display  php code in `php` file code will be excuted

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your problem? You want to execute php code in a html document?

Comment: @martin i **do not** want to execute php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ideas on how to display/present HTML tags on a webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443355/ideas-on-how-to-display-present-html-tags-on-a-webpage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ideas on how to display/present HTML tags on a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443355/ideas-on-how-to-display-present-html-tags-on-a-webpage)

Use the `<xmp>` tag instead of `<pre>`.

```
<xmp>
<html>
<body>This is my html inside html.</body>
</html>
</xmp>

You can use highlight_string() php function to display php code

<?php
highlight_string('<?php phpinfo(); ?>');
?>

Replace all occurences of < with &lt; (and optionally > with &gt;):

<pre>
&lt;?php echo 'hello world'; ?&gt;
</pre>
```

Comment: Replace all occurences of < with &lt; (and optionally > with &gt;):

<pre>
&lt;?php echo 'hello world'; ?&gt;
</pre>

Comment: is there any other way to do in php or i have to use only special codes

Comment: In php you can use function highlight_string(). http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php

Answer (score 0):

As "" tag is deprecated alternatively you can do like this:

```
<PRE>
&#60;A HREF="http://www.idocs.com"&#62;Cool Dude&#60;/A&#62;
</PRE>
```

Reff:http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/_XMP.html

Comment: no i dont want to use special hrml code to do this]